# QDarkStyle - How to modify widget properties?

Tags: pyqt5

I'm using PyQt5 and QtDesigner to build a simple app. 
I'm also using the QDarkStyle package to modify the ui appearance.

I'm trying to change a QTextBrowser widget's frame properties, like lineWidth, frameShape and frameShadow.

I cannot find out how to get to these properties and modify them.

Answer (score 0):

I could overwrite the stylesheet of the object from QtDesigner as such:

```
QTextBrowser#evidence_text_browser{
border-color: rgb(0, 79, 148);
background-color: rgb(34, 54, 75);
}
```